# Iterator.continually: cannot evaluate expression in Scala REPL

Tags: scala

Does anyone have any idea/explanation why REPL is stuck during evaluation of last expression? The weird thing is that it does not throw any exception or anything, just nothing happens.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40).

scala> val empty = Seq.empty[Int].iterator
empty: Iterator[Int] = empty iterator

scala> val emptyInfiniteIterator = Iterator.continually(empty).flatten
```

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what happens. When you define iterator in Scala REPL, some information about that iterator is printed, whether it's empty or not in particular:

```
scala> Iterator.continually(List(1)).flatten
res1: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

This information is returned by `toString` method of `Iterator`, which is defined like this:

```
override def toString = (if (hasNext) "non-empty" else "empty")+" iterator"
```

Basically, `hasNext` is called on newly created iterator. Now let's see what `hasNext` does in your case (`scala.collection.TraversableOnce.FlattenOps#flatten`):

```
  class FlattenOps[A](travs: TraversableOnce[TraversableOnce[A]]) {
    def flatten: Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
      val its = travs.toIterator
      private var it: Iterator[A] = Iterator.empty
      def hasNext: Boolean = it.hasNext || its.hasNext && { it = its.next().toIterator; hasNext }
      def next(): A = if (hasNext) it.next() else Iterator.empty.next()
    }
  }
```

Aha! `hasNext` recursively traverses the iterator trying to find either an end or single non-empty element. Which, in your case, never happens, as you have infinite iterator of empty elements. So, you have infinite loop which is triggered by REPL. You don't get `StackOverflow`, because tail recursion is used and in scala it's transpiled to while loop.

Comment: Good one. It should override `toString` as seen in `(1 to 10).iterator span (_ < 5)`.

Comment: @som-snytt, thanks for pointing out `toString`, for some reason I imagined that REPL uses something else for pretty printing values. Probably I had [ammonite](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL) in mind, which doesn't use `toString` for standard types. Anyway, now all pieces are in place.

Comment: Even if it did override `toString` differently, you would still have the same infinite loop when you tried to use the iterator for anything... what OP has created is an infinite loop waiting to happen, which should be clear if you understand what `flatten` means.

Comment: Will mark question as answered. Thanks a lot for explanation. Small question: is it really expected behavior from client code perspective? I would expect it to throw some exception to whatever.

Comment: @tkachuko, what exactly is unexpected in this case? In math, when you multiply zero by infinity, you get uncertainty. When you create such iterator, unless this particular case is explicitly covered, general rules apply and you get infinite loop. And infinite loops don't throw anything, they just hang.

Comment: REPL uses `ScalaRuntime.stringOf` which can avoid `toString`, but that doesn't help, because in general it wants to avoid calling `hasNext` for all sorts of effects (besides the effect of never returning). The iterator knows better how to describe itself.

Comment: Since it's not really documented, it's hard to say what's expected behavior. It's not obvious that composing empty iterators shouldn't yield an empty iterator that can report `!hasNext`. Some collections methods are explicit about "may not terminate for infinite collections".